# How do you indicate that a Panel is loading an external contentURL?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

If you have a Panel that is linked to some contentURL, it stays blank until the entire request is finished. Is there any way to first fill the Panel with some local 'loading' message until the external page is finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly load a `data.url('loading.html')` page in your panel when you create it.  Then once you want to load the external URL you just change the `contentURL` attribute of the panel.  I'm not sure that the `loading.html` page will stick around since the iframe used is supposed to be swapped out but that's how I'd approach the problem.